# is dirac gemma matrics form a group?

Tags: group-theory, physics, binary-operations

G={I ,γ^μ, σ^μυ, γ^5γ^μ}
Heres the set.
Is this form a group if yes under which binary relation?
i gotta submit my assigment.i tried commutator and anti commutator relations but enable to pove..

Comment: What is γ^5γ^μ ?

Comment: gemma 5 gemma mew